# How to hardcode few AccountIds to a storage in migration?

Tags: runtime-upgrade, storage-migration

During a storage migration I want to add few SS58 Address in one storage. How to hardcode it in migration script?

Answer (score 2):

See this tutorial on Substrate for the basics about migrations [Basic storage migration](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/storage-migrations/basic-storage-migration/), in this tutorial there is an example where it modifies the storage of a pallet (Nicks pallet) to include both a first name and an optional last name. The [script has to transform the values](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/storage-migrations/basic-storage-migration/#write-migrate_to_v2) to the new storage.

Your case is easier because if I understand correctly you just want to add some accounts into an storage.
To see how to hardcore the an address, see this SE previous question: [How to hardcode an address in the substrate runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66056225/how-to-hardcode-an-address-in-the-substrate-runtime).

A simple version of your code will look something like:

```rs
fn on_runtime_upgrade() -> frame_support::weights::Weight {
            let onchain_version = Pallet::<T>::on_chain_storage_version();
            if onchain_version < your_version {
                let account_hardcoded = AccountId::from_ss58check("account_hardcoded").unwrap();
                <YourStorage<T>>::put(account_hardcoded);
                // Return the weight consumed by the migration.
                T::DbWeight::get().reads_writes(1, 1)
            } else {
                log::info!(target: LOG_TARGET, "MigrateToV1 should be removed");
                T::DbWeight::get().reads(1)
            }
        }
```